# How to generalize this method for its duplicate/common logic?

Tags: refactoring, business-logic, dry

I've a method that apparently has quite some duplicate logic, I'd like to generalize it so that their duplicate logic could be shared and reused, also make my code more extensible for future additions.

```java
    public class GeneralizeExample {

        /**Apparently the logic in specificMethod is duplicated, how can we generalize them and make it extensible? In case there's SetThree, SetFour in the future that needs to be added to this method?*/

        public void specificMethod(DDBRecord ddbRecord, Set<String> incomingSetOne, Set<String> incomingSetTwo, String incomingString) {
            Set<String> existingSetOne = ddbRecord.getSetOne();
            if (existingSetOne == null) {
                if (!incomingSetOne.isEmpty()) {
                    ddbRecord.setSetOne(incomingSetOne);
                    ddbRecord.setSetOneCount(incomingSetOne.size());
                    existingSetOne = incomingSetOne;
                }
            } else if (existingSetOne != null) {
                if (incomingSetOne.isEmpty()) {
                    //remove this string from this set if it exists
                    existingSetOne.remove(incomingString);
                    int updatedSetOneCount = existingSetOne.size();
                    ddbRecord.setSetOneCount(updatedSetOneCount);
                    if (updatedSetOneCount == 0) {
                        existingSetOne.add("N/A");
                    }
                    ddbRecord.setSetOne(existingSetOne);
                } else if (!incomingSetOne.isEmpty()) {
                    if (existingSetOne.contains("N/A")) {
                        existingSetOne.remove("N/A");
                    }
                    //add this incoming set in
                    existingSetOne.addAll(incomingSetOne);

                    ddbRecord.setSetOne(existingSetOne);
                    ddbRecord.setSetOneCount(existingSetOne.size());
                }
            }

            //below is the exact same logic repeated on SetTwo
            Set<String> existingSetTwo = ddbRecord.getSetTwo();
            if (existingSetTwo == null) {
                if (!incomingSetTwo.isEmpty()) {
                    ddbRecord.setSetTwo(incomingSetTwo);
                    ddbRecord.setSetTwoCount(incomingSetTwo.size());
                    existingSetTwo = incomingSetTwo;
                }
            } else if (existingSetTwo != null) {
                if (incomingSetTwo.isEmpty()) {
                    //remove this string from this set if it exists
                    existingSetTwo.remove(incomingString);
                    int updatedSetTwoCount = existingSetTwo.size();
                    ddbRecord.setSetTwoCount(updatedSetTwoCount);
                    if (updatedSetTwoCount == 0) {
                        existingSetTwo.add("N/A");
                    }
                    ddbRecord.setSetTwo(existingSetTwo);
                } else if (!incomingSetTwo.isEmpty()) {
                    if (existingSetTwo.contains("N/A")) {
                        existingSetTwo.remove("N/A");
                    }
                    //add this incoming offer set in
                    existingSetTwo.addAll(incomingSetTwo);

                    ddbRecord.setSetTwo(existingSetTwo);
                    ddbRecord.setSetTwoCount(existingSetTwo.size());
                }
            }

            //do something w/ existingSetOne and existingSetTwo afterwards
        }

        class DDBRecord {
            private Set<String> setOne;
            private Set<String> setTwo;
            private int setOneCount;
            private int setTwoCount;

            public Set<String> getSetOne() {
                return setOne;
            }

            public void setSetOne(Set<String> setOne) {
                this.setOne = setOne;
            }

            public void setSetOneCount(int count) {
                this.setOneCount = count;
            }

            public Set<String> getSetTwo() {
                return setTwo;
            }

            public void setSetTwo(Set<String> setTwo) {
                this.setTwo = setTwo;
            }

            public void setSetTwoCount(int count) {
                this.setTwoCount = count;
            }
        }

    }
```

I've tried to come up with a data structure to apply OO ideas to wrap this around, but didn't really make it work, any ideas would be appreciated!

I'm open to any suggestions/modifications to make this logic duplicate reduction happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The approach you're looking for is a [code refactoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring) called "extract method" (or "extract function").  See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring#Techniques) and/or [here](https://refactoring.guru/extract-method).

You take the common code and extract it into its own private function.  They you "abstract" the code by having it take a parameter.  With that parameter, the function can be used starting with different values, and so, you will then call this private method from the two different places using a different parameter in each of the two calls.

I use the term "to abstract" as in introducing a parameter, which the way this term is used in lambda calculus: when we take some code, replace some (fixed) part with a variable, and then make the code into a function taking a parameter for this variable we introduced.

---

There will be a minor difficulty in doing `setSetOneCount` vs. `setSetTwoCount`.  There are several options:

a. Add the following or similar as follows

```
class CountedSet {
    Set<String> theSet;
    int count;
}
```

And modify DBRecord to use this type twice, then you can pass the proper set to the private method.  In some sense, there's a missing entity concept (a missing abstraction) by having two sets of paired fields — and this class make the missing abstraction manifest.

b. Have the private method take a lambda to call for doing the setting, and provide a different lambda from each call site.

There are other options:

Make DBRecord have only one `setCount` method and pass a parameter to tell it set 1 or set 2.  With that the private method can call the more generic `setCount` passing a parameter for set 1 or set 2; this value is supplied as another parameter by the caller of the private method.

Comment: You rock! Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation! I learned a ton!